# Can someone tell me why I get "Potential leak of an object" on CGColorCreateCopy?

Tags: ios, sdk, caemitterlayer, caemittercell

Here is my code -- Compiling on Xcode 6.3 for iOS8 and above:

```
//Create the emitter layer
CAEmitterLayer *emitter = [CAEmitterLayer layer];
emitter.emitterPosition = position;
emitter.emitterMode = kCAEmitterLayerOutline;
emitter.emitterShape = kCAEmitterLayerCircle;
emitter.renderMode = kCAEmitterLayerAdditive;
emitter.emitterSize = CGSizeMake(100 * multiplier, 0);

//Create the emitter cell
CAEmitterCell* particle = [CAEmitterCell emitterCell];
particle.emissionLongitude = M_PI;
particle.birthRate = multiplier * 1000.0;
particle.lifetime = multiplier;
particle.lifetimeRange = multiplier * 0.35;
particle.velocity = 180;
particle.velocityRange = 130;
particle.emissionRange = 1.1;
particle.scaleSpeed = 1.0; // was 0.3

particle.color = CGColorCreateCopy([UIColor colorWithRed:.5 green:.5 blue:.5 alpha:.5].CGColor);
UIImage *theimage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tspark"];
particle.contents = (__bridge id)(theimage.CGImage);
particle.name = @"particle";

emitter.emitterCells = @[particle];
```

I have been struggling with what to release!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ["Create Rule"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001148-103029) says that if the Core Foundation call has "Create" or "Copy" in the name, you must release it (or transfer ownership to ARC, which isn't relevant here).

The documentation for `CGColorCreateCopy` also makes this explicit and says:

> You are responsible for releasing this object using `CGColorRelease`.

So you could remedy this by releasing the object returned by `CGColorCreateCopy`.

```
CGColorRef colorRef = CGColorCreateCopy([UIColor colorWithRed:.5 green:.5 blue:.5 alpha:.5].CGColor);
particle.color = colorRef;
CGColorRelease(colorRef);
```

Obviously, much easier is to just avoid `CGColorCreateCopy` altogether:

```
particle.color = [UIColor colorWithRed:.5 green:.5 blue:.5 alpha:.5].CGColor;
```